# Get previous values when solving an ODE in Gekko

Tags: python, gekko

I'm trying to solve a DAE in Gekko, where some of the components will depend upon the solution to a convolution [integral](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?V_%7BCPE%7D(t_n)=%5Cfrac%7B%5CDelta&space;t%7D%7B%5CGamma(%5Calpha)Q%7D%5Csum_%7Bk=1%7D%5E%7Bn-1%7D(t_n-t_k)%5E%7B%5Calpha-1%7DI(t_k))

[image: Integral]

This requires a constant dt, but I'm sure that's somewhere in the options. Consequently, what I want to do is use a function to record the current value of a state variable in an array, and return the sum up to that point. Here was my attempt using one of the simple ODE examples:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO()    
class adder:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.i=m.Array(m.Param, 10)
        self.count=0
    def f(self, y):
        self.i[self.count]=y
        self.count+=1
        return sum(self.i)
a=adder()
m.Equation(y.dt()==-y+1+a.f(y)) 
m.time = np.linspace(0,5) 
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve()
```

but the solution 1) looks incorrect and 2) I can't print anything about the solution using the a.f() function and 3) even when I set the size of the `self.i` array to 1, it doesn't throw an out of bounds error so I expect it's not being called in the way I think. I've also seen people suggest using the `delay()` function, but I don't know how to access which timestep I'm currently in and to loop over each previous timestep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing continuous differential equations with discrete equations can be a challenge. Two recommendations are to either (1) convert the DAEs to a discrete form (such as with [Orthogonal Collocation on Finite Elements](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/OrthogonalCollocation)) or (2) use a continuous integral form of the convolution integral. The `m.integral()` function is available in Gekko to help with any integral expressions. See [How to solve integral in Python Gekko?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830404/how-to-solve-integral-in-python-gekko) and [Integral Objective (Luus)](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/IntegralObjective) for two examples of solving problems with continuous integrals.

Gekko calls functions only once when building the model. The model file is found in `m.path` as `gk0_model.apm` (text file) or by opening the folder with `m.open_folder()`. The model must be expressed symbolically so that it can be compiled for automatic differentiation.